# Is there a way to access and use console error messages?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 4 app that makes http requests towards different destinations. I want to display different messages for different http responses. Say, for `error 404` I want to display "Error 404" in an `iframe`.

In order to do that , I thought that maybe I can access these http responses and use them in my code, but I'm not sure this can be done.

Comment: You can create a simple Component and a route. Whenever you get a response 404 from API, just redirect to a specific route.

Comment: If you do a request, you expect a response. The response can have the status code 404. You can do an if statement on that. If the code is 404 the router redirects to your 404 component

Comment: Actually, I want to display the message in an `iframe`

Comment: May we know the reason why do you want to show this in iframe? Usually, we use an iframe in the case of external web-urls.

Comment: It's just what I was asked to do.

Comment: No idea why you would want to display the error in an iFrame, why not use a modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible to do this.

```
http.get(/*values*/).subscribe((res: Response) => {
  if (res.status === 404) {
       // redirect to error-page 
  }
)
```

You can access to the Response Status and redirect to your error page

Comment: I'm not sure this works, because I tried `console.log(res.status)` under if condition and I got nothing.

Comment: Did you do a request ? What do you get for console.log(res)